# Document Warehouse, Document AI Warehouse, CODE 409 error upon entering the project number

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

Issues and steps:
I'm having an issue with "Document AI Warehouse". Upon loading "https://documentwarehouse.cloud.google.com/" a promo pops up titled "User & Project Setting" and asks for the "Project number".

After entering the project number, and clicking on "save" it says "This project has not been configured, click here to configure your project." even though I've already done the configuration once.

When I try to redo the configure form it shows "CODE 409: Requested entity already exists".

Note: It worked initially after the first setup of the project. It suddenly stopped working though.

Troubleshooting:

- I have proper access to the DocWarehouse AI and signed up for DocWarehouse preview. I'm the project owner with more than sufficient authorization
- I have done the "Provision DocAI Warehouse" steps successfully.
- I tried clearing the cache and changing the browser

Answer (score 0):

Have you also joined the UI Preview Google Group? The Warehouse UI has been restricted to allowlisted users (which is a separate allowlist than for the product itself).

https://cloud.google.com/document-warehouse/docs/administer-warehouse#troubleshooting